# Trying to automate clicking in python fails

Tags: python-2.7, automation, pywin32

I've been trying to write a script in python to click around another window for me and take screenshots of it as it goes along. I've been able to capture screenshots and bring the window I need to the foreground with win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(). However once I've executed the command to set the new foreground window I can no longer control the mouse. All commands to move the mouse, click or otherwise no longer do anything. I've tried different tools from pyautogui to using win32 to move the mouse and they work before I execute the SetForegroundWindow function, but not after. Can anyone advise me?

Edit:
A snippet of code:

```
import win32gui, pyautogui

win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(None, 'Window Title')
pyautogui.moveTo(1050, 242)
pyautogui.click()
```

Basically this is what Ive tried and it pulls the window I want to the front but the mouse doesn't move nor click. I need it to move the mouse, click, take a screenshot, save it, and repeat for multiple reports in this other program.

Comment: Did you try pywinauto? http://pywinauto.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

I had essentially this exact same problem. What worked for me was to run the python script as administrator. The mouse move would work as long as my python IDE had the foreground, but as soon as I switched the foreground window the mouse move would produce an error.

The code I was using:

```
import pywinauto

pywinauto.win32functions.SetForegroundWindow(pywinauto.findwindows.find_window(title="Window Title"))
pywinauto.mouse.press(button='left', coords=(142, 388))
pywinauto.mouse.release(button='left', coords=(404, 388))
```